# One of our Apple TV 4K devices does not permit speaking the characters when entering a password

Tags: password, appletv, voice-dictation

Title says it all.

We have two Apple TV 4K devices. One of them lets us speak each character of a password when in a password data-entry screen. The other Apple TV 4K does not.

Is there some way to enable the speech-recognition feature for passwords?